# Trouble in translating C code into an OpenCL kernel

Tags: c, opencl

I have been unsuccessful in translating the following C function into an OpenCL kernel.

```
void Function2(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output, int32_t input_inter[64])
{
       int32_t Y[64];

       for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
          Y[i]= input_inter[i];

            int32_t k, l;

    for (k= 0; k < 8; k++)
  {
      idct_1d(&Y(k,0));
  }


    for (l=0; l < 64; l++)
  {
    printf("c%d: %d  ", l, Y[l]);
  }

}
```

My OpenCL kernel for the above function (WHICH DOES NOT WORK) is as follows:

```
__kernel void GPU_Function2(__global int *input, __global uchar *output, __global int Yin[64]){

     int Y[64];


    for (int i= 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        Y[i]= Yin[i];
    }


      unsigned int k= get_global_id(0);

    int Yc[8];

          if (k < 8)
        {

            idct_1D(&Y(k,0));               
        }

    for (int r= 0; r < 64; r++)
    {
      Yin[r]= Y[r];
    }

}

}
```

Argument 3 contains the values I need and ideally, I would pass it through `idct_1D` to get the expected output. However, `idct_1D` only takes in private variables so I transferred the contents of `Yin` in `Function_2` to `Y[64]`. After that as one can see, I did idct on `Y[64]` and after that put back the new values inside `Yin[64]` and expected to see the same output as my C code. But that has not worked.

**Please suggest how I can get the desired behavior for the OpenCL code of `Function_2`.**

**-----------------------------------------------------**

The function above gets its third input from the following OpenCL kernel, which works as it should.

```
__kernel void GPU_Function1(__global int *input, __global uchar *output, __global int Yin[64]) 
{

 int Y[64];
 unsigned int lin;
 unsigned int k= get_global_id(0);
 //unsigned int l= get_global_id(1);

        if (k < 8)
  {
      for (lin=0; lin < 8; lin++)      
            {
                Y(k, lin) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + lin], S_BITS);
               Yin[(k <<3) + lin]= Y(k, lin);

            }          
   }
}
```

My OpenCL host code for `Function1` and `Function2` is as follows:

```
    //Executing Function_1 on the GPU....

         ret = clSetKernelArg(Func1_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Input);
          ret |= clSetKernelArg(Func1_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Output);
          ret |= clSetKernelArg(Func1_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Intermediate);

          size_t globalForInverseDCT = 8;

          ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, Func1_kernel, 1, NULL, &globalForInverseDCT, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, DCT_Intermediate, CL_TRUE, 0, 64 * sizeof(cl_int), &Inter_DCT, 0, NULL, NULL);


      printf("----GPU output for Function1 --------\n");

       for (int w=0; w < 64; w++)
     {
          printf("g%d: %d  ", w, Inter_DCT[w]);
      }


    //Executing Function_2 on the GPU......

         ret = clSetKernelArg(Func2_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Input);
         ret |= clSetKernelArg(Func2_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Output);
         ret |= clSetKernelArg(Func2_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&DCT_Intermediate);

        size_t InverseDCT_1Dim= 8;

        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, Func2_kernel, 1, NULL, &InverseDCT_1Dim, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

      ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, DCT_Intermediate, CL_TRUE, 0, 64 * sizeof(cl_int), &Inter_DCT, 0, NULL, NULL);


            printf("-----GPU output for Function 2---------\n");

               for (int x= 0; x < 64; x++)
             {
                      printf("g%d: %d  ", x, Inter_DCT[x]);
              }
             exit(1);

  ////The remaining code.........
```

The result of the output buffer for Function_1 is this:

```
    ----GPU output for Function1 --------

        g0: -1600  g1: 0  g2: 0  g3: 0  g4: 0  g5: 0  g6: 0  g7: 0  g8: -3408  g9: 0  g10: 0  g11: 0  g12: 0  g13: 0  g14: 0  g15: 0  g16: -1960  g17: 0  g18: 0  g19: 0  g20: 0  g21: 0  g22: 0  g23: 0  g24: -336  g25: 0  g26: 0  g27: 0 
 g28: 0  g29: 0  g30: 0  g31: 0  g32: 648  g33: 0  g34: 0  g35: 0  g36: 0  g37: 0  g38: 0  g39: 0  g40: 672  g41: 0  g42: 0  g43: 0  g44: 0  g45: 0  g46: 0  g47: 0  g48: 200  g49: 0  g50: 0  g51: 0  g52: 0  g53: 0  g54: 0  g55: 0  g56: -288  g57: 0  g58: 0  g59: 0  g60: 0  g61: 0  g62: 0  g63: 0
```

The CORRECT output for `Function_2` (which I get when I run its normal C code) is this:

```
    c0: -1600  c1: -1600  c2: -1600  c3: -1600  c4: -1600  c5: -1600  c6: -1600  c7: -1600  c8: -3408  c9: -3408  c10: -3408  c11: -3408  c12: -3408  c13: -3408  c14: -3408  c15: -3408  c16: -1960  c17: -1960  c18: -1960  c19: -1960  c20: -1960  
c21: -1960  c22: -1960  c23: -1960  c24: -336  c25: -336  c26: -336  c27: -336  c28: -336  c29: -336  c30: -336  c31: -336  c32: 648  c33: 648  c34: 648  c35: 648  c36: 648  c37: 648  c38: 648  c39: 648  c40: 672  c41: 672  c42: 672  c43: 672  c44: 672  c45: 672  c46: 672  c47: 672  c48: 200  c49: 200  c50: 200  c51: 200  c52: 200  c53: 200  c54: 200  c55: 200  c56: -288  c57: -288  c58: -288  c59: -288  c60: -288  c61: -288  c62: -288  c63: -288
```

But the OpenCL equivalent of `Function_2` produces the following output which is different from the C code and incorrect:

```
    -----GPU output for Function 2---------
    g0: -1600  g1: 0  g2: 0  g3: 0  g4: 0  g5: 0  g6: 0  g7: 0  g8: -3408  g9: 0  g10: 0  g11: 0  g12: 0  g13: 0  g14: 0  g15: 0  g16: -1960  g17: 0  g18: 0  g19: 0  g20: 0  g21: 0  g22: 0  g23: 0  g24: -336  g25: 0  g26: 0  g27: 0  g28: 0 
 g29: 0  g30: 0  g31: 0  g32: 648  g33: 0  g34: 0  g35: 0  g36: 0  g37: 0  g38: 0  g39: 0  g40: 672  g41: 0  g42: 0  g43: 0  g44: 0  g45: 0  g46: 0  g47: 0  g48: 200  g49: 0  g50: 0  g51: 0  g52: 0  g53: 0  g54: 0  g55: 0  g56: -288  g57: -288  g58: -288  g59: -288  g60: -288  g61: -288  g62: -288  g63: -288
```

`idct_1D` in my `.cl` file looks like this:

```
void idct_1D(int *Y) 
{

int z1[8], z2[8], z3[8];


    but(Y[0], Y[4], z1[1], z1[0]);
    rot(1, 6, Y[2], Y[6], &z1[2], &z1[3]);
    but(Y[1], Y[7], z1[4], z1[7]);
    z1[5] = CMUL(sqrt2, Y[3]);
    z1[6] = CMUL(sqrt2, Y[5]);

    but(z1[0], z1[3], z2[3], z2[0]);
    but(z1[1], z1[2], z2[2], z2[1]);
    but(z1[4], z1[6], z2[6], z2[4]);
    but(z1[7], z1[5], z2[5], z2[7]);

    z3[0] = z2[0];
    z3[1] = z2[1];
    z3[2] = z2[2];
    z3[3] = z2[3];
    rot(0, 3, z2[4], z2[7], &z3[4], &z3[7]);
    rot(0, 1, z2[5], z2[6], &z3[5], &z3[6]);

    but(z3[0], z3[7], Y[7], Y[0]);
    but(z3[1], z3[6], Y[6], Y[1]);
    but(z3[2], z3[5], Y[5], Y[2]);
    but(z3[3], z3[4], Y[4], Y[3]);
}
```

I copied the [remaining contents](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/blob/master/tima_seq_version/src/idct.c) of `idct.c` into my `.cl` file.

Comment: I don't understand your code. For example, what is this function call syntax, `Y(k,0)`, on the array supposed to mean? It might help if you made a more minimal example. That said, what looks pretty suspicious to me is the fact that with the OpenCL version every work item is writing to the entire output without synchronization -- that is a race condition. For example, the iterations with `k` equal to `0` and `1` could be writing simultaneously to `Yin`, which is undefined behavior. Also if the correctness depends on iterating over `k` in the same order as the C code, that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @JohnDuck There is a preprocessor directive in my .cl file which reads `#define Y(i, j) Y[ (i << 3) + j]`. I even included the link for the `.h` file which contains all the preprocessor directives and macros in my question. You are correct in claiming that synchronization is not occuring in the above code. I put `Y[64]` in the local memory and copied and pasted the contents of `idct_1D` into a new function which takes local arguments. After making those changes, I started seeing better results.